# HTML5 attributes: name fname mname lname differences?

Tags: html, forms, validation, attributes, user-experience

I've been checking [web fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/input/form/label-and-name-inputs) and read the part of autocomplete. Really interesting but I found the following options inside the name HTML attribute.

```
name fname mname lname
```

I've only seen the `name` attribute. I've tried to find information but not finding anything on the web. Does anybody know if these attributes can be added or more information regarding them?

I suppose:

- fname: full name
- mname: middle name
- lname: last name

But this is plain imagination... let me know more information if you know what this is precisely.

Comment: According to that article, fname, mname and lname are not attributes, they're attribute values for the name attribute. Unlike the autocomplete attribute values, there's no support described for them in the HTML5 specs, but they may have the desired effect in some browsers.

Comment: @Alohi You are completely right. I see they are only recommended naming conventions, nothing to do with attributes or HTML attributes.